# inequality comparison of numpy array with nan to a scalar

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, nan, inequality

I am trying to set members of an array that are below a threshold to nan. This is part of a QA/QC process and the incoming data may already have slots that are nan.

So as an example my threshold might be -1000 and hence I would want to set -3000 to nan in the following array

```
x = np.array([np.nan,1.,2.,-3000.,np.nan,5.])
```

This following:

```
x[x < -1000.] = np.nan
```

produces the correct behavior, but also a RuntimeWarning, but the overhead of disabling the warning

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
...
warnints.resetwarnings()
```

is kind of heavy an potentially a bit unsafe.

Trying to index twice with fancy indexing as follows doesn't produce any effect:

```
nonan = np.where(~np.isnan(x))[0]
x[nonan][x[nonan] < -1000.] = np.nan
```

I assume this is because a copy is made due to the integer index or the use of indexing twice.

Does anyone have a relatively simple solution? It would be fine to use a masked array in the process, but the final product has to be an ndarray and I can't introduce new dependencies. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any comparison (other than `!=`) of a NaN to a non-NaN value will always return False:

```
>>> x < -1000
array([False, False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

So you can simply ignore the fact that there are NaNs already in your array and do:

```
>>> x[x < -1000] = np.nan
>>> x
array([ nan,   1.,   2.,  nan,  nan,   5.])
```

**EDIT** I don't see any warning when I ran the above, but if you really need to stay away from the NaNs, you can do something like:

```
mask = ~np.isnan(x)
mask[mask] &= x[mask] < -1000
x[mask] = np.nan
```

Comment: I agree about the logic, and I'm glad you pointed out that this isn't he usual nan-isn't-equal-to-nan issue. The issue for me when I try this is that it produces a Runtime Warning. One option is to to import warnings and catch it, but this is a lot of typing and overhead. I'm hoping for an economical alternative.

Comment: Does anyone know why `np.nan` allows comparison at all (always evaluating to `False` rather than raising a TypeError or something as `None < x` does)?  It causes all kinds of headaches if some nans escape out of numpy arrays into regular Python variables and you start using them with regular Python methods and expressions.

Comment: That's what NaN is supposed to do according to IEEE 754, you will get the same behavior, e.g. from `float('nan')`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN

Answer (score 18):

One option is to disable the relevant warnings with [`numpy.errstate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html):

```
with numpy.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
    ...
```

To turn off the relevant warnings globally, use [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html).

Comment: Thanks. I think there might be a safer way using the warning filter in warnings:

Comment: warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") and then afterwards

Comment: This is a global change too ... arguably fairly safe if reset immediately. However, as my note to Jamie hints, I was aware of the diabling approach. I was looking for something without this overhead. However I think your answer may help a lot of people.

Comment: You might use [errstate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.errstate.html) for a preference.

Answer (score 9):

[np.less()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.less.html#numpy.less) has a `where` argument that controls where the operation will be applied.  So you could do:

```
x[np.less(x, -1000., where=~np.isnan(x))] = np.nan
```

Comment: You can simply use `where=np.isfinite(x)`

Answer (score 2):

I personally ignore the warnings using the np.errstate context manager in the answer already given, as the code clarity is worth the extra time, but here is an alternative.

```
# given
x = np.array([np.nan, 1., 2., -3000., np.nan, 5.])

# apply NaNs as desired
mask = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=bool)
np.less(x, -1000, out=mask, where=~np.isnan(x))
x[mask] = np.nan

# expected output and comparison
y = np.array([np.nan, 1., 2., np.nan, np.nan, 5.])
assert np.allclose(x, y, rtol=0., atol=1e-14, equal_nan=True)
```

The numpy `less` [ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html) takes the optional argument `where`, and only evaluates it where true, unlike the `np.where` function which evaluates both options and then picks the relevant one.  You then set the desired output when it's not true by using the `out` argument.

Comment: Note that the `out=mask` keyword argument is required for this to work. Otherwise, np.less will return True in a skipped position

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late, but this is how I would do:

```
x = np.array([np.nan,1.,2.,-3000.,np.nan,5.]) 

igood=np.where(~np.isnan(x))[0]
x[igood[x[igood]<-1000.]]=np.nan
```