# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater

Tags: python, numpy, softmax

I tried to implement [soft-max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) with the following code (`out_vec` is a `numpy` vector of floats):

```
numerator = np.exp(out_vec)
denominator = np.sum(np.exp(out_vec))
out_vec = numerator/denominator
```

However, I got an overflow error because of `np.exp(out_vec)`. Therefore, I checked (manually) what the upper limit of `np.exp()` is, and found that `np.exp(709)` is a number, but `np.exp(710)` is considered to be `np.inf`. Thus, to try to avoid the overflow error, I modified my code as follows:

```
out_vec[out_vec > 709] = 709 #prevent np.exp overflow
numerator = np.exp(out_vec)
denominator = np.sum(np.exp(out_vec))
out_vec = numerator/denominator
```

Now, I get a different error:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater out_vec[out_vec > 709] = 709
```

What's wrong with the line I added? I looked up this specific error and all I found is people's advice on how to ignore the error. Simply ignoring the error won't help me, because every time my code encounters this error it does not give the usual results.

Comment: `out_vec` array contains `NaN` or `Inf` values?

Comment: @kvorobiev do you know how I could catch the warning so I could check?

Comment: Try `np.isnan(np.sum(out_vec))`

Comment: @kvorobiev yes, I meant how to actually _catch_ it (I call this code thousands of times, I can't just print the output).

Comment: Please, see my answer

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345843/inequality-comparison-of-numpy-array-with-nan-to-a-scalar

Answer (score 37):

Your problem is caused by the `NaN` or `Inf` elements in your `out_vec` array. You could use the following code to avoid this problem:

```
if np.isnan(np.sum(out_vec)):
    out_vec = out_vec[~numpy.isnan(out_vec)] # just remove nan elements from vector
out_vec[out_vec > 709] = 709
...
```

or you could use the following code to leave the `NaN` values in your array:

```
out_vec[ np.array([e > 709 if ~np.isnan(e) else False for e in out_vec], dtype=bool) ] = 709
```

Comment: Thanks @kvorobiev, but I can't do that - simply removing the elements will cause data loss...

Answer (score 14):

In my case the warning did not show up when calling this before the comparison (I had NaN values getting compared)

```
np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: There is no warnings module within numpy, this (`np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`) is accessing the warnings package built into python's standard library which numpy happens to import. The code is equivalent to `import warnings`, `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')`, and it will suppress all warnings generated by all code (not just numpy) unless you later re-enable warnings.

Comment: I did the warning suppression too with the warnings module but limited it to the few statements that needed it using: `with np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore'):`

Comment: `np.seterr(invalid='ignore')` seems like a better option

Comment: If you want to go the whole hog, try `np.seterr(all='raise')`

Answer (score 8):

IMO the better way would be to use a more numerically stable implementation of sum of exponentials.

```
from scipy.misc import logsumexp
out_vec = np.exp(out_vec - logsumexp(out_vec))
```

Answer (score 2):

If this happens because of your NaN value, then this might help:

```
out_vec[~np.isnan(out_vec)] = out_vec[~np.isnan(out_vec)] > 709
```

This does the greater operation for none NaN values and the rest remains the same. If you need the rest to be False, then do this too:

```
out_vec[np.isnan(out_vec)] = False
```

Comment: This should be the best answer!