# Scalar comparison with np.nan in python

Tags: python, numpy

What happens when I compare an integer or float with `np.nan` in python?

```
5 < np.nan?
np.nan > 100?
```

I ran those commands myself and got `False` every time. Is this a consistent behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [inequality comparison of numpy array with nan to a scalar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345843/inequality-comparison-of-numpy-array-with-nan-to-a-scalar)

Comment: yes. if you want to see if the value of a variable is actually NaN, use `np.isnan`. See also, `np.isfinite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct. As a matter of fact, the way that np.nan is written, you'll also get False if you try `np.nan == np.nan` or `np.nan = None`. As stated in the comments, you should use np.isnan instead.