# numpy array filter and replace

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have an array

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,np.nan])
```

I would like to replace anything which is less than 1.5 by `np.nan`, i.e. I would like

```
a = np.array([np.nan,2,3,4,np.nan])
```

how do I do that?

I did

```
 a[a<1.5] = np.nan
```

I got the following run time warning error in IPython (Py3.4) `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less`. Is this because my list had `np.nan`? Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Also is there a way doing this inline without assigning? Instead of doing

```
a[a<1.5]=np.nan 
return a
```

I can just do

```
 return a...
```

where that .... is something that need filling in.

Comment: @BradSolomon i meant, I am writing this in the middle of a program. is there an inplace replacement function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this [`RuntimeWarning`] because my list had np.nan?

Yes.

> Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

In your case, this warning can be safely ignored.  So that you don't accidentally suppress unrelated warnings, please *don't put anything else inside the context manager besides the one line shown*.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,np.nan])
>>> with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
...     a[a<1.5] = np.nan
...     
>>> a
array([ nan,   2.,   3.,   4.,  nan])
```

This operates in-place, a copy is not created here.  To return a copy, with the original `a` unmodified, prefer the [masked array approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46084469/674039).

Comment: I don't think it's actually about the in-place operation (well, `a[a<1.5]` = np.nan is also in-place) but about avoiding assignment so that it can be done in one-line.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that gets you to your return statement as desired:

```
mask = ~np.isnan(a)
mask[mask] &= a[mask] < 1.5
return np.where(mask, np.nan, a)
```

Example:

```
def ma_lessthan(arr, num):
    mask = ~np.isnan(arr)
    mask[mask] &= arr[mask] < num
    return np.where(mask, np.nan, arr)

print(ma_lessthan(a, 1.5))
[ nan   2.   3.   4.  nan]
```

`mask` credit to: [@Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25346972/7954504).

Comment: It should be mentioned: this creates a copy.

Comment: It is avoidable, and I showed [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46084308/674039).  Using a masked array approach is good too, mind you, I just thought this was worth mentioning because we often care about details of performance and memory usage when using numpy.