# max() and min() returns np.nan when the np array starts with np.nan

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

The `max()` and `min()` functions are both returning `np.nan` if I have an array that starts with `np.nan`

Here is where it works as expected:

```
>>> column_data = np.array([111, np.nan, 112, np.nan, 115, np.nan, 116, np.nan, 117, np.nan, 118, np.nan, 119])
>>> print(max(column_data))
119.0
>>> print(min(column_data))
111.0
```

Now I add an `np.nan` at the beginning of the array, and it screwed up

```
>>> column_data = np.array([np.nan, 111, np.nan, 112, np.nan, 115, np.nan, 116, np.nan, 117, np.nan, 118, np.nan, 119])
>>> print(max(column_data))
nan
>>> print(min(column_data))
nan
```

I've tried filtering out the nan elements, but still the same:

```
>>> print(max(i for i in column_data if i is not np.nan))
nan
>>> print(min(i for i in column_data if i is not np.nan))
nan
```

What happened here and how do I fix this?

Comment: what did you expect it to do?

Comment: for max() to give me 119 and min() to give me 111, like my first example where it was working fine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution and a bit of explanation:**

@user2357112supportsMonica proves a point, "The filter is failing because the objects retrieved from the array to represent the NaN value are different objects from `np.nan`":

```
print(np.nanmin(column_data))
print(np.nanmax(column_data))
```

Output:

```
111.0
119.0
```

See [inequality comparison of numpy array with nan to a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345843/inequality-comparison-of-numpy-array-with-nan-to-a-scalar) for more info.

**Documentation:**

As mentioned in the [documentation's](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html#numpy.amax) notes:

> NaN values are propagated, that is if at least one item is NaN, the corresponding max value will be NaN as well. To ignore NaN values (MATLAB behavior), please use nanmax.

Comment: The fact that `np.nan != np.nan` has nothing to do with this. Even if things were changed so that `np.nan == np.nan`, the results would be the same. The filter is failing because the objects retrieved from the array to represent the NaN value are different objects from `np.nan`.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Also would you know why it fails to work when the array starts with np.nan but still works well when it does not?

Comment: @Dan this is due to the way comparisons to `nan` values are handled. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345843/inequality-comparison-of-numpy-array-with-nan-to-a-scalar

Comment: @Dan Added documentation link

Answer (score 5):

This is because `i is not np.nan` is never evaluating to `False` and thus nothing is every getting filtered out. The correct way to test for `nan` is using [`np.isnan(...)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html). This should work correctly:

```
max(i for i in column_data if not np.isnan(i))
```

Also, you can use numpy methods for performing filtering, max and min as follows:

```
column_data[~np.isnan(column_data)].max()
```

However, if you only wish to calculate `max` and `min` for non-nan values and not do anything else with the non-nan values, @U10-Forward's answer is the better approach.