# Masked `np.nan` in the `np.ma.array` problem in jupyter

Tags: python, numpy, compare, nan, masked-array

Let's run in the Anaconda Jupyter the Python3 NumPy code:

```
y = np.ma.array(np.matrix([[np.nan, 2.0]]), mask=[0, 1])
m = (y < 0.01)
```

and we have the warning: `/.../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less`.

Substituting `np.nan` with `1.0` etc. --- no warning.

Why the `np.nan` can not be masked and then compared?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345843/inequality-comparison-of-numpy-array-with-nan-to-a-scalar

Comment: But for `m = (y != 0.01)` (or `==`) the `y[m]` is valid; for `m = (y[~np.isnan(y)] < 0.01)` is not valid --- the shape is changed.

Comment: Look at `y`.  Is that masked as you want it?

Comment: With `y = np.ma.array(np.matrix([[np.nan, 2.0]]), mask=[1, 0])` and masking
`m = (y < 0.01)` we have `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less`.  Changing to `m = (y != 0.01)` and adding `print(y, y.shape) ; print(y[m], y[m].shape)` we get expected: `[[-- 2.0]] (1, 2)` and
`[[-- 2.0]] (1, 2)`. But `m = np.isnan(y) ; m &= (y[~m] < 0.01)` gives the `print(y, y.shape) ; print(y[m], y[m].shape)` unexpected: `[[-- 2.0]] (1, 2)` and
`[] (1, 0)` -- shape changed.

Answer (score 1):

MA has several strategies to implementing methods.

1) evaluate the method on `y.data`, and make a new `ma` with `y.mask`.  It may suppress any runtime warnings.

2) evaluate the method on `y.filled()`   # with the default fill value

3) evaluate the method on `y.filled(1)`  # or some other innocuous value

4) evaluate the method on `y.compressed()`

5) evaluate the method on `y.data[~y.mask]`

multiplication, for example use `filled(1)`, and addition uses `filled(0)`.

It appears that the comparisons are done with 1).

I haven't studied the `ma` code in detail, but I don't think it does 5).

If you are using `ma` just to avoid the runtime warning, there are some alternatives.

- there's a collection of `np.nan...` functions that filter out `nan` before calculating
- there are ways of surpressing runtime warnings
- `ufuncs` have a `where` parameter that can be used to skip some elements.  Use it with an `out` parameter to define the skipped ones.

===

Looking a `np.ma.core.py` I see functions like `ma.less`.

```
In [857]: y = np.ma.array([np.nan, 0.0, 2.0], mask=[1, 0, 0])                                  
In [858]: y >1.0                                                                               
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[858]: 
masked_array(data=[--, False, True],
             mask=[ True, False, False],
       fill_value=True)
In [859]: np.ma.greater(y,1.0)                                                                 
Out[859]: 
masked_array(data=[--, False, True],
             mask=[ True, False, False],
       fill_value=True)
```

Looking at the code, `ma.less` and such are a `MaskedBinaryOperation` class, and use 1) - evaluate on the `data` with

```
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
```

The result mask is logical combination of the arguments' masks.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#operations-on-masked-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Making the issue more simple, let's assume:

```
y = np.ma.array([np.nan, 0.0, 2.0], mask=[1, 0, 0])
m = (y > 1.0)
print(y, y.shape) ; print(y[m], y[m].shape, m.shape)
```

and the output is:

```
[-- 0.0 2.0] (3,)
[2.0] (1,) (3,)
```

with the RuntimeWarning: `/.../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater`.

Changing:

```
...
m = (y != 2.0)
...
```

We get:

```
[-- 0.0 2.0] (3,)
[-- 0.0] (2,) (3,)
```

so we have a masked element and the result without any RuntimeWarning.

Changing now:

```
...
m = y.mask.copy() ; y[np.isnan(y)] = 9.0 ; y.mask = m ; m = (y > 1.0)
...
```

We get (without RuntimeWorning):

```
[-- 0.0 2.0] (3,)
[-- 2.0] (2,) (3,)
```

This work-around is however strange (by setting arbitrary value in the place of `np.nan` and mask saving). Comparing something with `masked` should be always `masked`, shouldn't it?

Comment: `np.ma` has functions like `less` and `greater` to properly handle the masking.  The operator overloads don't handle that.